# how can I present side menu under the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, jonkykong-sidemenu

I am using library https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu for make iOS app
but I don't know how to present sidemenu under the navigation controllers

I want like this one.
[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5q6x.png)

but my app shows this.

[my app is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b29kF.jpg)

Comment: Please attach also some code to replicate your implementation. And tell us exactly what you can't achieve: colors? text inside? width of the menu?... etc. But also posting the code you have tried so far would really engage more